# Do a search for first and last name ZEND

Tags: php, zend-framework

I did the following code but for some reason the search is not working is not looking first name and last name.
i get all table.

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();

$select = $table->select();
$select->where(
    'CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) LIKE ?', 
    '%' . strip_tags($search) . '%'
);

$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: is $search just a dot?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean?

Comment: Are you sure `$search` has a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();

$select = $table->select();
$select->from(...);
$select->where(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) LIKE %?%'), $search);

$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

Use combined `where` and `orWhere` methods

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();

$select = $table->select();
$select->where('firstname = ?', $search)
       ->orWhere('lastname = ?', $search);

$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select->where("CONCAT(name_first,name_last) LIKE ?","%$keyword%");
```